# Can I hide part of a commit message when using git log?

Tags: git, git-log

I use "Smart Commits" with git and JIRA, which means my commit messages look like this:

```
J5481-290 - #comment {panel:bgColor=#eae6ff}*Git Commit Message*\\Added IQ310-2 to *FB710* code, including populated interface{panel} #time 1m
```

I'd like to use `git log`, but omit part of the commit message, for example, removing the following texts:

- `#comment {panel:bgColor=#eae6ff}*Git Commit Message*\\`
- `{panel}`

I'm happy to leave everything else that is there for formatting on JIRA, but the above can just makes things difficult to read for other people who are looking later

Is there any way of doing this with `git log`?

Comment: Not with git alone, write an external script to process the output

Comment: You should change the format the smart commits use to give you a commit message with subject line and body (with an empty line between them). Then you can use `--oneline`.